# Не удается подключиться к базе данных jdbc

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

Вот имею такую проблему выполняю код в IntelliJ IDEA все нормально, а в Android Studio возникает ошибка. Что не так или это зависит от среды.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url = "****";
        String username = "*****";
        String password = "*****";
        String pass = null;

        System.out.println("Connecting database...");

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
            System.out.println("Database connected!");
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT password FROM student WHERE email='user3'";
            final ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                pass = rs.getString("password");
            }


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
        }

        System.out.println("Pass "+pass);
    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testconnectdb, PID: 7641
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testconnectdb/com.example.testconnectdb.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect the database!
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2747)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect the database!
        at com.example.testconnectdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802) 
     Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2276)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2025)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:778)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
        at com.example.testconnectdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802) 
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:301)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2197)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2025) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:778) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569) 
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219) 
        at com.example.testconnectdb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6845) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2700) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2808) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` - вы пытаетесь подключится к БД в UI потоке. На форуме данная проблема уже 100 раз обсуждалась, так что воспользуйтесь поиском.

Comment: [offtop] угораю с местного поисковика - тот вопрос "похож" на любой с меткой `android`, но только не на этот)))